# AJAX post request to third party REST api

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel, teamwork-projects

. I am using laravel backend as API and angular as frontend which calls laravel api. Laravel api access the teamwork api through basic authentication using curl.

Now I am working with teamwork Api. Trying to create a comment using the API.
API documentation describes following.

```
    {
  "comment": {
    "body": "Reply to earlier comment",
    "notify": "",
    "isprivate": false,
    "pendingFileAttachments": "",
    "content-type": "TEXT"
  }
}
```

//ref : http://developer.teamwork.com/comments#creating_a_commen

in my ajax call i have used following

```
  var data = $.param({
    'body' : commentBodyValue,  //variable
    'notify': "",
    'isPrivate':false,
    "pendingFileAttachments": "",
    "content-type": "TEXT"
  });
```

My post does not give error, but it also do not create a new comment too. What am I missing? I think i failed to arrange data according to the format allowed in api. Can you kindly help me to fix it?

### Edit:

Angular Controller:

```
//add new comment
$scope.addComment = function(taskId,commentAuthorId)
{
  var commentBod  = document.getElementById("commentBody");
  var commentBodyValue = commentBod.value;
  console.log("new comment : "+ taskId + commentBodyValue);
  //submit the post request
  //$http.post();
  //using jquery function param to serialize 
  var data = $.param({
    'body' : commentBodyValue,
    'notify': "",
    'isPrivate':false,
    "pendingFileAttachments": "",
    "content-type": "TEXT"
  });
  var config = {
      headers : {
          // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;',
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  }
  var url = "http://abounde.com/portal/api/post_comment/"+taskId;
  $http.post(url,data,config)
  .then(
    function(response){
      //success
      console.log("response : Submitted :D  " + response);
    },
    function(response){
      //failure
      console.log(response);
    }
  );

}
```

### Edit 2

Laravel route and controller
**Routes:**
        //post comment to resource
        Route::post('post_comment/{task_id}',[
            'uses'=>'PortalController@postComment',
            'as'=>'portal.client.postComment'
        ]);

**Controller:**

```
    //post comment at task
        public function postComment(Request $request, $task_id)
        {
            $secretApiKey = $request->session()->get('secretApiKey');
            if(!empty($secretApiKey)){
            //post the msg
                $this->callTeamworkApi($secretApiKey,"tasks/".$task_id."/comments.json");

            }else{
                return response()->json(['response'=>"Not Logged In"]);
            }           
        }


//authentication method

    public function callTeamworkApi($secretApiKey, $apiCallString)
    {
            //cURL
        $password = "xxx";
        $channel = curl_init();
        //options
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, "http://projects.abounde.com/".$apiCallString); // projects.json?status=LATE gets all late projects
        curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                    array(
                      "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($secretApiKey . ":" . $password)
        ));


        $msg = curl_exec($channel);
        curl_close($channel);
        return response()->json(['res'=>$msg]);

    }
```

EDIT 3: Contacted with teamwork Api support.
After their advice i came up with following code

```
  //post comment at task
    public function postComment(Request $request, $task_id)
    {
        $secretApiKey = $request->session()->get('secretApiKey');
        if(!empty($secretApiKey)){

        //post the msg
            $comment=array();
            // $comment['body']=$request->input('body');
            // $comment['notify']=$request->input('notify');          
            // $comment['isprivate']=$request->input('isprivate');
            // $comment['pendingFileAttachments']=$request->input('pendingFileAttachments');
            // $comment['content-type']=$request->input('content-type');


            $comment['comment']['body']="test";
            $comment['comment']['notify']="";
            $comment['comment']['isprivate']=false;
            $comment['comment']['pendingFileAttachments']="";
            $comment['comment']['content-type']="text";


            $this->callTeamworkPostApi($secretApiKey,"tasks/".$task_id."/comments.json",json_encode($comment));
            //var_dump($comment);
            //return response()->json(['response'=>"Trying"]);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['response'=>"Not Logged In"]);
        }           
    }
}
```

///

```
  public function callTeamworkPostApi($secretApiKey, $apiCallString,$comment)
{
        //cURL
    $password = "xxx";
    $channel = curl_init();
    //options
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, "http://projects.abounde.com/".$apiCallString); // projects.json?status=LATE gets all late projects
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                array(
                  "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($secretApiKey . ":" . $password)
    ));
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $comment);


    $msg = curl_exec($channel);
    curl_close($channel);
            var_dump($msg);
    //return response()->json(['res'=>$msg]);


}
```

var_dump($comment) gives

```
string(107) "{"comment":{"body":"test","notify":"","isprivate":false,"pendingFileAttachments":"","content-type":"text"}}"
```

However the api still do not save the comment. It has to be a curl post method issue. Right?

Edit 4:
I have done a var_dump(curl_getinfo($channel));

this gave me following response.

```
array(26) { ["url"]=> string(55) "http://projects.abounde.com/tasks/8199861/comments.json" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(500) ["header_size"]=> int(229) ["request_size"]=> int(311) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.5) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.109) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.109) ["size_upload"]=> float(107) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(214) ["download_content_length"]=> float(0) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(107) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.5) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(13) "23.23.184.208" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=> int(80) ["local_ip"]=> string(11) "192.168.0.6" ["local_port"]=> int(31657) }
```

The response code 500 may points to the fact that teamwork has some kind of internal issues.

Comment: Are you experiencing a problem with your Laravel PHP talking to the Teamwork API or the AngularJS talking to your Laravel PHP?

Comment: Can you put up your controller code

Comment: @JaredRolt right now I am scratching my head. I think the problem is me failing to interpret the documentation properly. so the problem is when i am submitting data from angular to laravel api.

Comment: @HamzaDairywala I edited my post. Now it has angular controller

Comment: Are you sure you are not having a CORS issue.  Have you checked the response to your AJAX call in the browser dev tools to see what the actual response is?

Comment: So `http://abounde.com/portal/api` is the url of your Laravel API?
Can you show your API controller code.
Can you debug to check that your API controller action is being hit by the Ajax call.

Comment: http://abounde.com/portal/api/post_comment/{resource_id}/comments.json can you please check for this route  in the routes.php file

Comment: @JodyBoucher it is not cors issue. Browser shows response with list of comments from the api. API uses same url for get and post.

Comment: @HamzaDairywala Please check now. I edited with all code used :)

Comment: the error is at this line i suppose $this->callTeamworkApi($secretApiKey,"tasks/".$task_id."/comments.json");   you can not pass comments.json like this

Comment: @HamzaDairywala I am passing it as url string. It works fine when i am getting comments. problem is while posting. :S

Comment: @Anik i have posted the explanation and answer below hope it resolved your issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue i found out is that you are not passing your comment data which you received from the frontend to the curl the request in callTeamworkApi().Try below code and see if you get your desired output or not

```
//post comment at task
    public function postComment(Request $request, $task_id)
    {
        $secretApiKey = $request->session()->get('secretApiKey');
        if(!empty($secretApiKey)){

        //post the msg
            $comment=array();
            $comment['body']=$request->input('body');
            $comment['notify']=$request->input('notify');          
            $comment['isPrivate']=$request->input('isprivate');
            $comment['pendingFileAttachments']=$request->input('pendingFileAttachments');
             $comment['content-type']=$request->input('content-type');


            $this->callTeamworkApi($secretApiKey,"tasks/".$task_id."/comments.json",json_encode($comment));

        }else{
            return response()->json(['response'=>"Not Logged In"]);
        }           
    }


 //authentication method

public function callTeamworkApi($secretApiKey, $apiCallString,$comment)
{
        //cURL
    $password = "xxx";
    $channel = curl_init();
    //options
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, "http://projects.abounde.com/".$apiCallString); // projects.json?status=LATE gets all late projects
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                array(
                  "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($secretApiKey . ":" . $password)
    ));
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $comment);


    $msg = curl_exec($channel);
    curl_close($channel);
    return response()->json(['res'=>$msg]);

}
```

Comment: i see what you did. Its a progress. However it still do not fix the issue, Comments are not passing into teamwork api . SO they are not yet saved, 
I tried 
`$r = $this->callTeamworkApi($secretApiKey,"tasks/".$task_id."/comments.json",json_encode($comment));`

and printed $r to see what the json return it gets, it shows empty header array 
From inspect element
`{"response":{"headers":{}}}`

Comment: @Anik have set curl parameters please update the  callTeamworkApi() as i have coded and than try. first do var_dump($comment) in  callTeamworkApi() so that we come to know if you are actually receiving data from frontend

Comment: Please check the edit 3. I did what you asked me to do.

Comment: @Anik one thing is sure now we are receiving data from front end now do var_dump for the curl request object and see what it is printing

Comment: var_dump($msg); //output : bool(true)

var_dump($channel) //output : resource(200) of type (Unknown)

@hamza dairywala

Comment: @Anik true and response code 200 you get when you have a successful request now we need check it with API side that is the API is receiving proper data or not ?

Comment: Ok, Only thing i can do right now is check my account with teamwork to see if comment is being saved. And they are not. :S how else i can check?

Comment: @Anik Okay if you still need any help than just comment down

Comment: I posted solution.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution Found:**
While calling to the teamwork API, it is essential that the content-type is set to Json. and the information should be in header file. header variable should be a multi array which takes authentication and content type information.

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($secretApiKey . ":" . $password);
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";


    //pass it as variable
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

And then it works like charm.

returns following after creation of the comment.

```
{"commentId":"4294639","STATUS":"OK"}
```